# uses-permission android

Tags: android, permissions

In the AndroidManifest.xml, I have added all uses-permission, and now I want to remove permissions that I don't need them. I don't use camera or vibrate.. I use just simple functions ajax, I use Internet to extract data from server, and I use the local storage, so I want to know the uses-permission that shoudn't be deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two are enough for your case..

1. **I use just simple functions ajax, I use Internet to extract data from server,**

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```
2. **and I use the local storage,**

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Following are the Permission for you to write in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```