# Android Studio with Cloud Firestore: Not writing to the database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I am currently working on an Android Studio project for my senior project. This project in a nutshell is an event creator. I am using Cloud firestore as my database but I am having issues. I have supplied the code below; when I hit my submit button, the log will print that the button was pushed, the function has started and also that it is about to begin the code to submit the document to firebase, but it neither prints out if it was successful or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**Here is the Java code for the activity:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "EventSaved";
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //texts
    private EditText eventTitle;
    private EditText eventAddress;
    private EditText eventState;
    private EditText eventCity;
    private EditText eventZip;
    private EditText eventDate;
    private EditText eventTime;
    private EditText eventRules;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

        //views
        eventTitle = findViewById(R.id.eventTitle);
        eventAddress = findViewById(R.id.eventAddress);
        eventState = findViewById(R.id.eventState);
        eventCity = findViewById(R.id.eventCity);
        eventZip = findViewById(R.id.eventZipCode);

        //buttons
        findViewById(R.id.submitButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.clearButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.submitButton){
            Log.d(TAG, "Submit Button was Pushed!");
            saveEvent();
        } else if (i == R.id.clearButton){
            //reset the form
        }
    }//end onClick

    private void saveEvent(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Save Event function started");
        String title = eventTitle.getText().toString();
        String address = eventAddress.getText().toString();
        String city = eventCity.getText().toString();
        String state = eventState.getText().toString();

        Map<String, Object> event = new HashMap<>();
        event.put("title", title);
        event.put("address", address);
        event.put("city", city);
        event.put("state", state);

        Log.d(TAG,"Begin Write to Database!");
    // Add a new document with a generated ID
    db.collection("events")
            .add(event)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference(){
                    @Override
                     public void onSuccess(DocumentReference 
                     documentReference){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Success!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

And for reference; here is also my build.gradle for the app:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
```

Here is the Log of what happens when I hit the submit button:

```
03-12 12:09:59.759 8394-8394/com.example.seniorsemproject D/EventSaved: Submit Button was Pushed!
03-12 12:09:59.759 8394-8394/com.example.seniorsemproject D/EventSaved: Save Event function started
03-12 12:09:59.759 8394-8394/com.example.seniorsemproject D/EventSaved: Begin Write to Database!
03-12 12:09:59.889 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 349K, 10% free 4135K/4552K, paused 12ms, total 15ms
03-12 12:10:00.049 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lio/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel$DefaultNetworkCallback; (11)
03-12 12:10:00.049 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lio/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel$DefaultNetworkCallback;' failed
03-12 12:10:00.049 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'io.grpc.android.AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel$DefaultNetworkCallback', referenced from method io.grpc.android.AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel.configureNetworkMonitoring
03-12 12:10:00.049 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 945 (Lio/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel$DefaultNetworkCallback;) in Lio/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel;
03-12 12:10:00.069 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000b
03-12 12:10:00.069 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lio/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel$DefaultNetworkCallback; (11)
03-12 12:10:00.069 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lio/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel$DefaultNetworkCallback;' failed
03-12 12:10:00.089 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3215 at 0x0d in Lio/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder$AndroidChannel;.configureNetworkMonitoring
03-12 12:10:00.169 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 374K, 10% free 4270K/4712K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
03-12 12:10:00.239 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/remote/AndroidConnectivityMonitor$DefaultNetworkCallback; (349)
03-12 12:10:00.239 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/remote/AndroidConnectivityMonitor$DefaultNetworkCallback;' failed
03-12 12:10:00.249 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AndroidConnectivityMonitor$DefaultNetworkCallback', referenced from method com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AndroidConnectivityMonitor.configureNetworkMonitoring
03-12 12:10:00.249 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 6888 (Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/remote/AndroidConnectivityMonitor$DefaultNetworkCallback;) in Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/remote/AndroidConnectivityMonitor;
03-12 12:10:00.249 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000b
03-12 12:10:00.249 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/remote/AndroidConnectivityMonitor$DefaultNetworkCallback; (349)
03-12 12:10:00.249 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/remote/AndroidConnectivityMonitor$DefaultNetworkCallback;' failed
03-12 12:10:00.249 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xd9e6 at 0x0d in Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/remote/AndroidConnectivityMonitor;.configureNetworkMonitoring
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory, referenced from method com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.copyMemory
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18707: Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.copyMemory (JJJ)V
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0005
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory, referenced from method com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.copyMemory
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18708: Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.copyMemory (Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;JJ)V
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0007
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte, referenced from method com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.getByte
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18709: Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.getByte (J)B
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte, referenced from method com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.getByte
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18710: Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.getByte (Ljava/lang/Object;J)B
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong, referenced from method com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.getLong
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18711: Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.getLong (J)J
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByte, referenced from method com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.putByte
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18714: Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.putByte (JB)V
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByte, referenced from method com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.putByte
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18715: Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.putByte (Ljava/lang/Object;JB)V
03-12 12:10:00.359 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-12 12:10:00.459 8394-8423/com.example.seniorsemproject D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 376K, 10% free 4408K/4848K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-12 12:10:01.699 8394-8416/com.example.seniorsemproject V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Found the solution in another question listed. Needed to add a seperate permission to allow the external write. I figured it was something to this sort but couldn't find the right bit of code.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071279/uses-permission-android